# HTTPotion.get with "Referer" in header

Tags: curl, elixir

This is the first time I'm working with `Elixir`, so I'm having some issues with my first app. I'm trying to implement the equivalent of the following `curl`-request in elixir with the help of `HTTPotion`:

```sh
$ curl -s -X GET https://secure.us.playstation.com/playstation/psn/profile/public/userData?onlineId=eagon1337 --referer https://secure.us.playstation.com/logged-in/trophies/public-trophies/ | python -mjson.tool
{
    "avatarUrl": "//static-resource.np.community.playstation.net/avatar_m/3RD/UP40731301009_65ED8105B0C68DC79ABC_M.png",
    "curLevel": "3",
    "handle": "eagon1337",
    "isPlusUser": "1",
    "progress": "15",
    "totalLevel": "",
    "trophies": {
        "bronze": "44",
        "gold": "0",
        "platinum": "0",
        "silver": "1"
    }
}
```

Which sends the following Request-Header:

```
> GET /playstation/psn/profile/public/userData?onlineId=eagon1337 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: secure.us.playstation.com
> Accept: */*
> Referer: https://secure.us.playstation.com/logged-in/trophies/public-trophies/
```

I came up with the following Elixir code:

```
defmodule PS4 do
    def helloWorld do

        name = "eagon1337"
        url = "https://secure.us.playstation.com/playstation/psn/profile/public/userData?onlineId=" <> name
        headers = [{"Accept", "*/*"},
                   {"Host", "secure.us.playstation.com"},
                   {"Referer", "https://secure.us.playstation.com/logged-in/trophies/public-trophies/"},
                   {"User-Agent", "curl/7.30.0"}]

        IO.puts "Getting " <> url

        response = HTTPotion.get url, headers: headers

        IO.puts response.body

    end
end
```

Which results in

```
iex(1)> PS4.helloWorld
Getting https://secure.us.playstation.com/playstation/psn/profile/public/userData?onlineId=eagon1337
** (HTTPotion.HTTPError) req_timedout
    (httpotion) lib/httpotion.ex:209: HTTPotion.handle_response/1
          (ps4) lib/ps4.ex:14: PS4.helloWorld/0
```

Running the whole request against http://httpbin.org/get results in a pretty smooth header (with additional removing of the "host"-header):

```
iex(1)> PS4.helloWorld
Getting httpbin.org/get
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "0", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Referer": "https://secure.us.playstation.com/logged-in/trophies/public-trophies/", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.30.0"
  }, 
  "origin": "92.77.68.151", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}

:ok
```

Obviously the requested URL expects a specific Referer. But why is it working with curl, but not via my Elixir approach? What am I missing?

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/elixir/

Answer (score 1):

It's not direct answer, but using `http://us.playstation.com/` instead of `https://secure.us.playstation.com` seems working. So I'm wondering it might be related to ssl part (haven't been able to find out the background yet).